# Visual SourceSafe 6: Resetting all working folders

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, archiving, sourcesafe-6.0

I've got a few old sourcesafe repositories which I want to delete.  Before deleting them, I want to get the latest version of all code out recursively and then archive this code.

Various projects within the repositories have "working code" folders set which means that when I recursively get everything, code goes everywhere.

I'm trying to find a way to clear all working folders from a repository.
I've tried:

- googling
- looking through Tools->Options
- looking at the "set working folder" dialog
- looking at the "get multiple" dialog (but not closely enough - see answer below)
- looking into the behind-the-scenes file structures for anything obvious I could nuke

Alternatively, if there's a way of backing the code of the repository up which frees it from requiring sourcesafe to view, that would also be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<Edit>Although the below actually does what I stated I wanted, there is an easier way to accomplish getting the latest version of code in the structure it appears in in the repository, which is to tick the "Build Tree (override working folders)" in the "Get Multiple" dialog.</Edit>**

OK, worked it out.  In the sourcesafe file structure, there is a folder called "users", within this will be your windows username, within this will be a ss.ini file.

Editing ss.ini to remove any entries which are in square brackets (and the text immediately under these sections) got rid of all working folder information for me.  Note: It may also have lost some other information, but this is of no concern to me as I need only to get the latest version of code.

Example extract of file:

```
... more file above here ...
Preview_Rect (TQPC0137) = 321, 215, 703, 524, 1024, 768

Viewer_Font (TQPC0222) = Courier, 10, 400,, 0

Dft_Report_Type = 2
PrjFilesRpt_IncFiles = Yes
PrjFilesRpt_NamesOnly = No


... remove these sections below ...
[$/TQ/LRI/DataCaptureTest]
Dir (PC0137) = C:\PROJECT\DATACAPTURETEST

[$/AutoReference]
Dir (PC0137) = G:\WORKING CODE VBNET\TEST

[$/]
Dir (PC0222) = C:\WORKING CODE
Dir (PC0204) = G:\WORKING CODE VBNET\BOB
Dir (PC0118) = G:\WORKING CODE VBNET\BOB
Dir (PC0137) = G:\WORKING CODE VBNET\BOB
Dir (PC0168) = G:\WORKING CODE VBNET\BOB
... more file after this (but, in my instances, all the same type of stuff ...
```